# discrepancy in demographics in Soylent Green

Tags: soylent-green

The title card at the start (2:28) of the 1973 movie *Soylent Green*<sup>{1]</sup> reads:

> THE YEAR: 2022
> THE PLACE: NEW YORK CITY
> THE POPULATION: 40,000,000

Soon after (3:43), a New York City police officer is told that a murder had taken place "out of your jurisdiction, across the city line into Philadelphia". That seems to imply that New York and/or Philadelphia had grown so large as to border one another.

The police officer soon thereafter (4:24) notes that "there are twenty million guys out of work in Manhattan alone just waiting for my job, and yours too".

How can there be twenty million guys looking for work in Manhattan alone if the entire New York City had a population of forty million, presumably only half of whom are guys and some of whom are too young to work?

Now, New York City doesn't seem to include the Bronx at this point<sup>[2]</sup>, which tends to weaken my question slightly. But, even if New York City is just Manhattan, how can fully half its population be guys looking for work?

---

<sup>[1] [IMDb](//www.imdb.com/title/tt0070723/). [Wikipedia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soylent_Green). [Full movie on the Internet Archive](//archive.org/details/soylentgreen_201907). Timestamps in the question above refer to the latter version.</sup>

<sup>[2] The police officer is told (3:58) that a certain criminal "has a record in the Bronx, can be extradited. Get him the hell out of Manhattan." That seems to imply that the New York City Police Department's jurisdiction doesn't include the Bronx.</sup>

Comment: https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-hyperboles.html

Comment: I'll take 'what is hyperbole' for $500, please Alex.

Comment: The title card is likely intending to speak the truth of the film’s reality, while “twenty million guys” spoken by a schmuck with clearly no apparent expertise in population or employment data science is over-generalizing about things he probably doesn’t quite know the fine details of.

Comment: Does it really matter if its 20 million prospective applicants or 5 million, or 1 million?   The point is, you screw up, theres essentially an endless supply of replacements, its not a workers market its an employers market.  Once thats the case, the actual figures dont matter - see above comments for “hyperbole”.  Or in other words, how many billions of times have you been told not to exaggerate and yet you still do it? 

Comment: I thought this was going to question how in *Make Room, Make Room* the population of the dystopian future overpopulated United States could be only slightly higher than our actual population today.

Comment: Guys doesn’t always mean males.

Comment: re: NYPD jurisdiction not including the Bronx: It does, today, in reality. Don't assume that the studio (or the author) didn't take liberties with reality for the benefit of story.